# Convert S3 object name into S3 object url (python)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, hex, urlencode

I uploaded an image called

```
'Pepper, Pig (#PP).jpg'
```

to my S3 bucket.  I noticed that the corresponding object url created by AWS is:

```
'Pepper#2C+Pig+(%23PP.jpg)'
```

In other words, it converts all of the spaces into + and converts the comma and the hash into hex.  It does not change the parentheses.

Does this type of encoding have a special name? And is there some way to convert strings into this AWS object url naming convention?

Comment: Yes, it is called url encoding. Which programming language do you use?

Comment: Python.  I tried using urllib.parse.quote_plus, but I noticed that converts the parentheses to hex, whereas aws does not convert them to hex.  For example urllib encodes '(hello).jpg' as '%28hello%29.jpg' whereas the aws url would just be '(hello).jpg'

Comment: Both formats will work: `https://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/Pepper%2C+Pig+(%23PP).jpg` and `https://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/Pepper%2C+Pig+%28%23PP%29.jpg`

Comment: Super, thanks so much.  I just assumed it wouldn't work because the two url's looked different, but it does!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As John pointed out in the comments, the AWS title is url encoded, so in python, so to convert the S3 object name to the S3 object url, we can just use:

```
import urllib
object_name = 'Pepper, Pig (#PP).jpg'
object_url = urllib.parse.quote_plus(title)
```

The results is:

```
'Pepper%2C+Pig+%28%23PP%29.jpg'
```

Which works perfectly as when referencing this object in S3.